# Value of expression doesn't change

Tags: c#

I'm trying to move the cursor using linear interpolation. My problem is that the value of `y0 + (y1 - y0) * ((x - x0) / (x1 - x0))` never changes despite the fact that x changes. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
public void MoveCursor(int x1, int y1)
    {
        int y, y0, x, x0;

        y0 = Cursor.Position.Y;
        x0 = Cursor.Position.X;

        for (x = x0; x >  x1; x--)
        {
            y = y0 + (y1 - y0) * ((x - x0) / (x1 - x0));

            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(x,y);
            Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("X:{0} Y:{1}", x, y);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging that method?

Comment: Are you missing that `/` is integer division, not floating point division, when the operands are integers?

Comment: Eric: exactly, thank you. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using floats:

```
 y = (int)(y0 + (float)(y1 - y0) * (x - x0) / (x1 - x0));
```

Comment: It is important to use floats on the denominator also.

Comment: The operations * and / will be executed in order. As soon as an operation is done between a `float` and an `int`, the `int` will first be converted to a `float`.